# What does the error "double cannot be dereferenced" mean?

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors, double

I understand that the ArrayList can't hold any primitive data
but how can i call my method horseFeed() into the driver alongside my Arraylist constructor so that i don't get a double dereferenced error

Also can someone explain to me what a double dereferenced error is and why I'm getting it, please help

The method is in my class

```
public class horse
{
  .
  .
  .


  //took out a lot of code as it was not important to the problem

  public String horseFeed(double w)
  {
    double sFeed= w*.015;
    double eFeed= w*.013;
    String range = sFeed + " < " + eFeed;
    return range;
  }
}
```

This is the ArrayList class

```
import java.util.*;
public class horseStable
{
 . 
 .
 . 
 public double findHorseFeed(int i)
 {
   double weight = horseList.get(i).getWeight();
   return weight;

  }
}
```

This is the Driver

```
public class Main 
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
  //returns the weight of the horse works fine
  System.out.println(stable1.findHorseFeed(1)); 
  // This is supposed to use the horseFeed method in the class by using the horse's weight. Where can i place the horseFeed method without getting an error?
  System.out.println(stable1.findHorseFeed(1).horseFeed()); 
  }
 }
```

Comment: It is not clear on which line you are getting this error. Please remove those bits of code that are not contributing to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that you tried to invoke a method on a `double` value - in Java, `double` is a primitive type and you can't call methods on it:

```
stable1.findHorseFeed(1).horseFeed()
             ^               ^
      returns a double   can't call any method on it
```

You need to invoke the method on the correct object, with the expected parameters - something like this:

```
Horse aHorse = new Horse(...);
aHorse.horseFeed(stable1.findHorseFeed(1));
```

The method `horseFeed()` is in the `Horse` class, and it receives a parameter of type `double`, which is returned by the method `findHorseFeed()` in the `HorseStable` class. Clearly, first you need to create an instance of type `Horse` to invoke it.

Also, please follow the convention that class names start with an uppercase character.

Answer (score 0):

`findHorseFeed()` returns a `double`, on which you cannot call the `horseFeed()` method (it returns a `double`, not a `horse` object)

First you need to write (and subsequently call) another method to return a horse object that you can then call `horseFeed()` on.

In class `horseStable` you'll want a method like

```
public horse findtHorse(int i) {
    horse myhorse = horseList.get(i);
    return myhorse
}
```

You can probably also refactor `findHorseFeed` to just `.getWeight()` on `getHorse()`:

```
public double findHorseFeed(horse myhorse) {
    double weight = myhorse.getWeight();
    return weight
}
```

then you can call:

```
horse myHorse = stable1.findHorse(1);
String range = myHorse.horseFeed(stable1.findHorseFeed(myHorse));
```